# Play/Pause HTML5 video using CSS selectors

Tags: css, html, html5-video

On my page I have a <video> tag. In my CSS I can style this video tag using the following selector:

```
.current video{
  width:400px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Is it possible to start the video as well using css? I found the relevant looking property `animation-play-state:running;`, however this has a different usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot configure video playback in CSS. However, you can set the HTML [`autoplay`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-media-autoplay) attribute, like this:

```
<video src="video.mov" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

Comment: I would like the video to start playing when the css selector is matched :), not before.

Comment: @Ove Well, in that case, can't you start playing the video from the JavaScript code that's modifying the CSS classes in the first place?